# Correct capitalization for domain specific phrase?

Tags: capitalization

I am currently developing a webpage for the local underwater basket-weaving club, and they have a yearly course called "Learn to Weave". Encountering this phrase in multiple pages and e-mails, I am unsure if it should be capitalized, or how.

Which one of the following would be the most correct phrase, and why?

- Learn to weave
- Learn to Weave
- Learn To Weave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where the phrase is denoting the proper name of the course, it should be capitalized as the course name is. Where it literally means "learn to weave", then it should be capitalized according to whatever normal rules you'd use. The course itself would typically be capitalized using [title-case rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case#Headings_and_publication_titles), i.e. "Learn to Weave".